# Fine-Uploader title of the uploaded file

Tags: fine-uploader

First, i'm sorry for my bad english but I hope you'll understand my problem..

I'm trying to use FU to upload songs on a server.

I understood how worked the parameters in general but I cannot change the title of my songs.
I would like that users have to select a song (only one). onSubmit, an input appears to let him select the title of his song.
Until here, no problem.
But after uploading this song (when the drop area shows again) when I want to upload another one, it takes the same title than the one I chose before.

I'll try to explain it better.

1. I choose a song.
2. The drop area is hidden onsubmit
3. An input appears to let the user change the title of his song
4. A OK button appears to validate when the title has benn chose
5. On click (ok button), the upload begin and the drop area is visible again
6. Same scenario
7. For the second song, whatever I enter in the input, it will take what was written in the input for the first song

Here is my code:

```
.on('submit', function(){
                $('.qq-upload-drop-area').hide();
                $('.qq-upload-button-selector').hide();
                $('.valider_chanson').show();
            });


        $('.valider_chanson').click(function(){    //button OK

            var input_title = $('#song_title').val();
            var dropzone_titre = $('.dropzone_titre');
            var drop_area = $('.qq-upload-drop-area');
            var upload_button = $('.qq-upload-button-selector');

            if(input_title == "")
            {
                //Titre de chanson obligatoire
                alertify.alert('Vous devez sélectionner un titre pour votre morceau');
            }
            else{
                //On recache le bouton jusqu'au prochain upload
                //$('#uploadSelectedFiles').hide();

                //On renomme le champ visible par le nom saisi
                //$('.qq-editable').text(input_title);
                //$('.qq-edit-filename').val(input_title);
                var new_input_title = $('.qq-edit-filename').val();

                //On lance l'upload
                SongsUploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
                //dropzone_titre.hide();

                $('.valider_chanson').hide();
            }
        });

.on('upload', function(event, id, name){
                var fileItemContainer = $(this).SongUploader('getItemByFileId', id);
                var enteredTitle = $('#input_title').val();
                //enteredTitle = $(fileItemContainer).find('INPUT[name="title"]').val();
                    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {title: enteredTitle}, id);
                //$(this).fineUploader('setName', {title: enteredTitle}, id);
                $(this).fineUploader.setName(enteredTitle, id);
                })

// I dont understand very well how the 'setParams' and 'setName' works
```

I would really thankfull if someone could help me.. Thanks by advance!
Cordially,
-B

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reverse the parameters for `setName`.

Right now, you have `setName(enteredTitle, id)`, but it should be `setName(id, enteredTitle)`

```js
.on('upload', function(event, id, name){
    var fileItemContainer = $(this).SongUploader('getItemByFileId', id);
    var enteredTitle = $('#input_title').val();
    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {title: enteredTitle}, id);
    $(this).fineUploader('setName', id, enteredTitle);
})
```

Source: [setName in the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setName).

**Update**

Below is how you would set the filename and upload a single file at a time. Note that if you provide a `qq-edit-filename-selector` element which serves as an input element. This is already provided in the default temoplate, so you may not need to change that at all.

```
   <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // when a user clicks this button is should trigger the upload
    $("#upload_button").on('click', function(){
        $("#fineuploader-traditional").fineUploader("uploadStoredFiles");
    });

    // but we want to hide the button until we have a file
    $("#upload_button").hide();

    $("#fineuploader-traditional").fineUploader({
        debug: true,
        multiple: false,
        template: "qq-template",
        autoUpload: false,
        request: {
            endpoint: "/uploads"
        }
    })
    .on('submit', function(event, id){
        // a file has been submitted, so let us show the upload button
        $("#upload_button").show();
    })
    .on('validate', function(){
        // Do not allow more than one file to be in the queue at a time.
        var status = [qq.status.SUBMITTING, qq.status.SUBMITTED, qq.status.QUEUED, qq.status.UPLOADING, qq.status.UPLOAD_RETRYING],
            queuedFiles = $(this).fineUploader('getUploads', {
                status: status
            });

        if (queuedFiles.length > 1) {
            alert("One at a time");
            return false;
        }
    })
    .on('complete', function(){
        // hide the button again (may want to check for success)
        $("#upload_button").hide();

    });


});
```

You can now click on the filename and edit it. The new filename will be sent to the server under the `qqfilename` parameter.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your quick answer.
I add the setName parameter to my code but I don't understand how I can get it to assimilate each song to each entered title.

I'm trying to get it with the getName parameter like this:

.on('complete', function(event, id, filename, responseJSON){
var UploadedFileName = $(this).fineUploader('getName',id);
          alert(UploadedFileName);
}

But it always alert me the original filename and not the name I entered in my input.
Can you please explain me how can I get this name because I didn't understand very well the documentation..
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the formatting.
Here is my code:  
<code>
 .on('complete', function(event, id, filename, responseJSON){
var UploadedFileName = $(this).fineUploader('getName',id);
          alert(UploadedFileName);
</code>

Comment: You'll need to post your entire client-side code for me to completely understand what you are doing. In the meantime, I've updated my answer to show the most basic way to change the filename.

Comment: @BryanM. If you want to allow users to edit file names, simply include the proper template with the edit filename elements included.